# Is it possible to refactor this Controller create method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, architecture, refactoring

Is there a design pattern or good practices for this kind of view inizialization code? In this case, depending on the parameter ($tipoPedido) it sets up the view in different ways:

```
 public function create(Request $request, RepositorioDepositos $repositorioDepositos, RepositorioEmpresas $repositorioEmpresas)
    {
        $tipoPedido = strtoupper($request->tipo);

        $datos = ['action' => "/api/pedidos", 'tipo' => $tipoPedido];


        if ($tipoPedido == TipoRemitoStock::ESPECIAL) {

            if (!tengoPermiso(\App\Permiso::STOCK_CREAR_REMITO_ESPECIAL)) {
                return mensajeErrorNoTienePermiso();
            }

            $datos['origen']  = null;
            $datos['destino'] = $repositorioDepositos->getTodosNoFinalizados();
        }
        
        
        elseif ($tipoPedido == TipoRemitoStock::INTERNO) {
            $datos['origen']  = $this->getMisPosiblesDepositosOrigen($repositorioDepositos);
            $datos['destino'] = $this->getMisPosiblesDepositosDestino($repositorioDepositos);
        }
        
        
        elseif ($tipoPedido == TipoRemitoStock::PROVEEDOR) {
            $datos['origen']      = null;
            $datos['destino']     = $this->getMisPosiblesDepositosDestino($repositorioDepositos);
            $datos["proveedores"] = $this->proveedoresConOCsDeMaterialesAprobadas($repositorioEmpresas);
        }
        
        else {
            die("Tipo de pedido no implementado: " . $tipoPedido);
        }


        $vista = view('ventas.formulario-abm-pedido', $datos);

        return $vista;
    }
```

Now we need to add 3 new types so there will be 3 new elseif blocks.

Comment: I think using `switch` is a better and clearer way

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways that you could make this work out better. The first would be to group commonalities like I've done below looking for overlaps in logic.

```php
public function create(
    Request $request,
    RepositorioDepositos $repositorioDepositos,
    RepositorioEmpresas $repositorioEmpresas
) {
    $tipoPedido = strtoupper($request->tipo);

    $datos = ['action' => "/api/pedidos", 'tipo' => $tipoPedido];

    // Make sure the request is in what is expected
    //   you could have the TipRemitoStock class have a ->toArray()) to get all these values
    if (!in_array($tipoPedido, [TipoRemitoStock::ESPECIAL, TipoRemitoStock::INTERNO, TipoRemitoStock::PROVEEDOR])) {
        die("Tipo de pedido no implementado: " . $tipoPedido);
    }
    
    // If it is ESPECIAL validate there's some permission?
    if($tipoPedido === TipoRemitoStock::ESPECIAL && !tengoPermiso(\App\Permiso::STOCK_CREAR_REMITO_ESPECIAL)) {
        return mensajeErrorNoTienePermiso();
    }

    // Always set and allow TipoRemitoStock::INTERNO to override
    $datos['origen'] = null;
    
    // Always set and allow TipoRemitoStock::ESPECIAL to override
    $datos['destino'] = $this->getMisPosiblesDepositosDestino($repositorioDepositos);
    
    switch($tipoPedido) {
        case TipoRemitoStock::INTERNO:
            $datos['origen'] = $this->getMisPosiblesDepositosOrigen($repositorioDepositos);
            break;
        case TipoRemitoStock::PROVEEDOR:
            $datos["proveedores"] = $this->proveedoresConOCsDeMaterialesAprobadas($repositorioEmpresas);
            break;
        case TipoRemitoStock::ESPECIAL:
            $datos['destino'] = $repositorioDepositos->getTodosNoFinalizados();
            break;
    }
    
    return view('ventas.formulario-abm-pedido', $datos);
}
```

The code above is identical to what you put with slightly less lines. This isn't really the pattern though that I would recommend when considering adding many more.

I would look into using the Decorator pattern - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#PHP This pattern would offer the flexibility to continually build new passes which can extend the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a good candidate for the Strategy Pattern. ([There's an example of it applied to laravel here](https://medium.com/@joeleyamu/the-use-of-strategy-design-pattern-when-developing-a-payment-system-in-laravel-6eb64c021cfa))

Basically you'd want to pick a response strategy according to the kind of order that comes in the request, looking forward to

- Be able to add new order types without altering (or with minimal alteration) of the current controller
- Allow a limited whitelist of implemented order types, and for each perform due access roles and input verification
- Handle extraeous order types gracefully

For the first part the controller would need to know that, whatever new order type is implemented, it's safe to assume it will provide certain array of `datos` in response to a tuple of `$repositorioDepositos` and `$repositorioEmpresas`, as well as abort the process if the user lacks permission.

You could make an interface `PedidoStrategyInterface` in the likes of:

```
interface PedidoStrategyInterface {

   public function getDatos(
        RepositorioDepositos $repositorioDepositos,
        RepositorioEmpresas $repositorioEmpresas
   );

   protected function checkPermission();
   
}
```

And a class for each order type.

```
class PedidoEspecial implements PedidoStrategyInterface {

   private array $datos = [
                'origen' => null,
                'action' => "/api/pedidos", 
                'tipo' => TipoRemitoStock::ESPECIAL
   ];
   protected function checkPermission() {
      abort_if(
        !tengoPermiso(\App\Permiso::STOCK_CREAR_REMITO_ESPECIAL), 
        403, 
        'Not so fast!'
      );
   }

   public function getDatos(
      RepositorioDepositos $repositorioDepositos,
      RepositorioEmpresas $repositorioEmpresas
   ) {
      $this->checkPermissions();
      return array_merge($this->datos,[
        'destino' =>  $repositorioDepositos->getTodosNoFinalizados()
      ]);
   }
}
```

(For those strategies which do not need to validate permissions an empty method will do.)

```
class PedidoInterno implements PedidoStrategyInterface {
      // same as above, but it fills the keys origen and destino
}

class PedidoProveedor implements PedidoStrategyInterface {
      // same as above, but it fills the keys destino and proveedores
}
```

With that approach it would be trivial to add a new order type, but we need another couple of steps to get there. For example, you could bind certain order types to the above classes, in your ServiceProviders:

```
public function register() {
      $this->app->bind(TipoRemitoStock::ESPECIAL, PedidoEspecial::class);
      $this->app->bind(TipoRemitoStock::INTERNO, PedidoInterno::class);
      $this->app->bind(TipoRemitoStock::PROVEEDOR, PedidoProveedor::class);
}
```

Now, in your controller, you could pass most of your current logic elsewhere:

```
public function create(
     Request $request, 
     RepositorioDepositos $repositorioDepositos, 
     RepositorioEmpresas $repositorioEmpresas
) {
  $tipoPedido = strtoupper($request->tipo);

  /** 
   * The controller would know that the order type is implemented 
   * because it would be bound to the container. Otherwise we abort 
   * with `Tipo de pedido no implementado`.
   */
  if(!app()->bound($tipoPedido)) {
     abort(400,'Order Type Not implemented');
  }
  /**
   * For those order types that are bound, you ask the
   * container to get you an instance:
   */
  $orderStrategy=app()->make($tipoPedido);
  
}
```

let's pause here. `$orderStrategy` can be *any current strategy or any other that could be added in the future*, given it implements `PedidoStrategyInterface` and we have explicitly bound it in our serviceProvider. Knowing that, and knowing that everything else will be rejected, then this controller couldn't care less, because it just needs to do:

```
   if(!app()->bound($tipoPedido)) {
      abort(400,'Order Type Not implemented');
   }

   $orderStrategy=app()->make($tipoPedido);
   
   return view(
      'ventas.formulario-abm-pedido', 
       $orderStrategy->getDatos( $repositorioDepositos, $repositorioEmpresas)
   );
```

And, as you sure have noticed, this means the logic of

```
 getMisPosiblesDepositosOrigen
 getMisPosiblesDepositosDestino
 proveedoresConOCsDeMaterialesAprobadas
```

Needs to be moved to the order strategies. They can inherit from each other to take advantage of common methods. There a several other optimizations that could be introduced. For example, it looks pointless to have those repositorios fooling around when they won't be used in the controller itself, right? They should be injected onto the order strategies.